WARNING | Failed to process .ini file \Users\<username>\.android\avd\INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\<username>\.android\avd\INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 4684.ini for reading. WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\<username>\.android\avd\INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 4684.ini for reading. (2x) WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading. WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading. WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\<username>\.android\avd\INFO | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash-34.2.16.db, detection is enabled for process: 4684.ini for reading. WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading. WARNING | Failed to process .ini file (null)\config.ini for reading. WARNING | Failed to process .ini file
When I try to open a device, that will pop up,, I'm still stuck at this point here is my device.
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM CPU @ 2.20GHz   2.20 GHz
Windows 10 Pro
